# "Automatically set exception at clean up" exception showing in Control Room

Tags: blueprism

When reviewing in cases in a work queue the message:

> Automatically set exception at clean up

appears as the exception reason.

Why has Blue Prism set the case as an exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the clean up phase is the phase that happens after the process is done. There are two important things that are done then - cleaning of objects and cleaning of the queue.

For every object used in the process, the action "finalize" is executed. It's rarely used option - i've never scen it used.

During the cleaning of the queue, all locked tems are marked with exception that you're asking about.

So, my advice is to investigate how it was possible that an item has been left behind.

Comment: Thanks a lot Andrzej.

Answer (score 1):

The "Automatically set exception at clean up" happens when you the process finishes or gets terminated without unlocking the item queue that is being processed.

I imagine that you are getting data from the Work Queue using and action like "Get next item". Every time that you get an item from the queue BP locks it to prevent other bot from processing it at the same time.

To solve your problem, use the "Mark Completed" if you finished processing that item, or the "Unlock Item" if you want to keep working with it later.

Answer (score 1):

"Automatically set exception at cleanup" appears when you have picked up a case and not declared it as completed or exception WHILE THE PROCESS FINISHES WITHOUT ANY FURTHER ACTION ON THE QUEUE ITEM. In other words, if you leave the queue item to be in the locked state and your process execution finishes, it will still go in the said reason.